# SQL Заполнить недостающие данные в таблице

Tags: sql

есть таблица oc_product_attribute

```
||product_id||attribute_id||language_id||text||
|      1     |      11     |      1     |  30 |
|      1     |      11     |      2     |  30 |
|      2     |      11     |      1     |     |
|      2     |      11     |      2     |  40 |
|      3     |      11     |      1     |  50 |
|      3     |      11     |      2     |     |
|      4     |      11     |      1     |  60 |
|      5     |      11     |      2     |  70 |
```

Заполнение таблицы:

Вариант 1 (product_id = 1) - все заполнено для двух языков. Все ОК

Вариант 2 (product_id = 2 и 3) - поле text не заполнен для одного из языков

Вариант 3 (product_id = 4 и 5) - в таблице нет записи одного из языков

Нужно привести всю таблицу к Варианту 1.

Т.е. для варианта 2 - заполнить поле text, а для варианта 3 - создать недостающую запись в таблице.

Как правильно составить sql-запрос?

Comment: Что за СУБД? Значение text = (product_id + 2) * 10 или предопределённые значения?

Comment: Так, на вскидку, можно попробовать: 1. Добавить уникальный индекс по product_id-language_id. 2. Cоздать функию/процедуру, в которой в цикле от 1 до MAX(product_id) будут делаться 2 запроса (если MySQL): `INSERT IGNORE INTO oc_product_attribute (строки для каждого языка)` и `UPDATE oc_product_attribute SET text=(product_id+2)*10 WHERE text IS NULL OR text =''`. 3. ну, и, сотвенно, вызвать эту функцию/процедуру. Это общая схема.

Comment: MYSQL
Для варианта 1 нужно брать значения из существующего другого языка.
Что-то типа:

     UPDATE oc_product_attribute
     SET text = (SELECT text FROM oc_product_attribute WHERE 
     attribute_id = 16 AND language_id = 2 AND text >0)
     WHERE attribute_id = 16 
     AND language_id = 1;

Comment: Для варианта 2 - как-то проверять, для какого языка есть запись и создавать такую же, только с другим language_id

Comment: Решайте задачу по очереди, сначала получите те записи для которых нет записи с другим языком или у другого языка поле text не заполнено, т.е. вроде `select * from tab A where not exists(select 1 from tab B where B.product=A.product and B.lang!=A.lang and B.text is null)`. А после смотрите что такое `insert on duplicate key update` и пишете его с вставкой из первого запроса. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472229/